# Check if a query contains things out of the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

As a result of the query I want to have all the Directors that are not in a list I send in the `List` with directors. But I don't know how I can fix this. I already tried this with `Contains` and some other things.

Just no idea how to do it.

```
public List<MovieDirector> GetDirectorsPossibleForMovie(int MovieID, List<Director> director)
{
    List<MovieDirector> directors =
    (from item in db.MovieDirectors where item.MovieId != MovieID && item.Director != director orderby item.Director.Lastname select item).ToList<MovieDirector>();
    return directors;
}
```

Additional info: Databases `MovieDirector` and `Movie` are linked, but also `MovieDirector` and `Director`.

Thanks!

Comment: You say that you want Directors, but your method returns MovieDirectors.  Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Enigmativity's answer might work if the MovieDirector class has its hash code and equals methods set up right, but it will pull almost all of your MovieDirector objects from the database, only to discard the ones associated with the directors in your list.

Assuming you have a primary key `DirectorId` to differentiate one director from another, you should be able to do something like this to produce an SQL query that will exclude the specified directors in the first place:

```
var directorIds = director.Select(d => d.DirectorId);
var mds = db.MovieDirectors.Where(x => x.MovieId != MovieID && 
                                       !directorIds.Contains(x.DirectorId))
          .ToList();
return mds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public List<MovieDirector> GetDirectorsPossibleForMovie(
    int MovieID, List<Director> director)
{
    var mds = db.MovieDirectors.Where(x => x.MovieId != MovieID).ToList();
    mds = mds.Where(x => !director.Contains(x.Director)).ToList();
    return mds;
}
```

Comment: You can't except Directors from MoveDirectors.

Comment: `Except` isn't possible because there needs to be some <MovieDirector> and not some <Director>

Comment: "I want to have al the Directors that are not in a list"  Which is the equality criteria of Director objects.

Comment: There is a list with directors in it. So with Linq I thougt it would be possible to check it with the Director object.

item.Director != director.   I can make instead of the Object Director a list of integers if you like --> List<int> directors where that I will put the ID in this list

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - Thanks for spotting that for me. I think I was kind of tricked by the variable names. Fixed now.

Comment: @Enigmativity , OK, but `director.Contains(x.MovieDirector)` is check reference equality and i not sure that is enough.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan , You're right. My query still gives the movies that are in the List.